# Can't choose Boot Order in Asus UEFI BIOS - detecting M.2 NVME clone as SATA

Tags: boot, bios, clone, nvme, m.2

I have just bought an Asus FX504GD laptop, which had a 1TB HDD installed and a free M.2 slot. I have taken the HDD out of it, mounted it on my PC, wiped it using `diskpart`, `clean`, and reinstalled the HDD into the laptop.

I have bought a Crucial MX500 500GB M.2 disk, installed it into a 2.5" SATA enclosure, put it in a HDD dock, and cloned my existing Windows 10 PC to it using ToDo EaseUS.

Usually if I am doing a HDD to SSD clone, or an SSD to SSD clone, I can just put the newly cloned SSD in any random PC and it will boot into Windows, as if it was the same PC.

However, with this laptop, it is not detecting any NVME drives in the BIOS. Instead it is detecting both the 500GB M.2 drive and the 1TB HDD as SATA drives.

In the BIOS, the Boot Order has "Windows Boot Manager" listed. The option to add a boot device is greyed out. There is nothing listed when I select Delete Boot Device. I have upgraded the firmware from version 303 to 310. I have disabled Fast Boot. I have wiped the Secure System Keys; and I have disabled Secure Boot. I cannot see any other options relating to NVME being Auto/Disabled, as described online. Nor can I see anything else about CSM.

How can I boot from my M.2 drive?

Here are some photos of the BIOS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Crucial MX 500GB m.2 is only SATA. This is at least what the specs say:
[Link to description](http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/ct500mx500ssd4).

M.2 is a Form Factor. NVMe is the Controller or Interface. Most m.2 SSD's are NVMe, but yours I think is not!

Can you boot the OS from the SATA or doesn't this work either?

Comment: That would probably explain it! I can't seem to find a way to boot into it using SATA. I think you're right - it's m.2 SATA, not m.2 NVME. The description for this Samsung NVME drive says that the write speeds are much better than SATA: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-MZ-V6E500BW-500GB-Express-Solid/dp/B01M20VBU7/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1534712171&sr=8-8&keywords=m.2+nvme+500 - time for an RMA I think! Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the end I bought the Samsung NVME and I've had no problems since then!